# Dynamical height of List element brings total Chaos

Tags: wordpress, css, dynamic, height

I want to have some list elements that got a dynamically adjusting height via css.

**For better understanding:** I am inserting via *::before* a number that I count via *counter-increment* (thats the big ones)

Problem is that nothing that I tried so far brings me even close to what i want to archive. If you change the window size everything gets shoven down...

**It should look like this:**
[image]

I tried:

```
clear: both; on every element (except the li)
height: auto; on every element
```

I've already read through some posts but nothing really worked for me.

Dont ask why am I trying to get it done with css... ;)
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the problem? I see well displayed site.

Comment: Try resizing the window.

Comment: I did. eventually will be two columns below each other which is expected.

Comment: resizing the window will stretch the element and a huge whitespace comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a little help from Rich.

the missing height and top was causing the trouble:

```
.page-id-3606 .product_thumbnail_wrapper::before {
content:'';
background: url('...');
height: 130% !important;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
clear: both;
top: -65px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an absolute positioning on your image and thumbnail wrapper which is causing huge problems, look at the adjusted CSS below:

```
.page-id-3606 .product_thumbnail_wrapper .product_thumbnail a img {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
}
.page-id-3606 .product_thumbnail a::before {
 counter-increment: section;
 content: "0" counter(section) "";
 font-size: 10em;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 /* top: 100px; */
 /* left: 50%; */
 line-height: 0;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center !important;
 box-sizing: border-box !important;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #464646;
 display: block !important;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #464646;
 /* transform: translate(-50%, 0); */
 margin: 0 !important;
 z-index: 10 !important;
}
```